# How to secure requests from angular (or any js) application (web-site) to parse server?

Tags: javascript, security, parse-platform, parse-server

For now we are using `APP_ID` and `JS_KEY` to make requests for parse server. We have registration on our site and after email validation user could create groups, send messages, and etc.

It's easy to limit logged in user rights with `CLP` and `ACL` for reading some data, but **how to forbid somebody to** write a script that would use our `APP_ID` and `JS_KEY` (that he could get just from "Network" tab of debugger), then login with valid credentials and **overflow parse database with some dummy data**? What ways of preventing it do you know?

Would appreciate your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

A few points to remember when using parse-server.

- Don’t write the master key in the source codes of the clients. They don’t need it.
- Use ACL in your code.
- Use Parse Server 2.2.1 or above to enjoy CLP.
- Set enableAnonymousUsers to false which prevents anonymous calls to the API.
- Modify the index.js file to use the Allow Client Class Creation option. Disable at the production stage.

The relevant snippet of code in the index.js now looks as follows:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  enableAnonymousUsers: process.env.ANON_USERS || false,
  allowClientClassCreation: process.env.CLIENT_CLASS_CREATION || false,
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your points, most of them we already have, but some others will check! Btw, maybe you know some software to work on parse server that could filter requests by frequensy depending on url, user IP and other params? I think it'll be good idea to additionaly protect site from DDoS.

Comment: @Ratmir there is a number of things you can do over and above to prevent attacks and brute force etc. Things like express-brute and other middleware packages. There are several packages on NPM that are dedicated to this!